# Problema con un div mal cerrado

Tags: html

Tengo un problema, no sé si será un `div` mal cerrado o mal implementado pero me está causando bastantes problemas porque no logro encontrarlo.

En esta imagen se puede observar los `grid`, de `carousel` que tiene un tamaño de 10, pero "evaluaciones" que tiene un tamaño de 2 queda abajo. Noté en la web y el problema es un `div` mal cerrado pero no lo logro encontrar.

[image: IMG1]

Aquí muestro cómo se ve en la web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`col-md-10` debiera mostrarse cerrado y a continuación `col-md-2`

Dejaré los códigos respectivos de `index.php`,`carousel.php` y por último `navDerecho.php`.

**index.php**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon.png">
    <title>Noticias</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<?php include ('vista/overall/botones.html') ?>

<body class="pb-0">

    <div class="row">
        <?php include('vista/overall/menu.php'); ?>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <?php  include('vista/overall/carusel.php');  ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <?php   include('vista/overall/navDerecho.php'); ?>
            <br>
        </div>

        <?php include('vista/overall/contenedor.php');?>

        <br>
        <br>

        <?php include('vista/overall/footer.html'); ?>
    </div>

    <!-- /container -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
    </script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <script src="/noticiasfinal/model/ajax.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**carusel.php**

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
    </ol>
    <?php
            $link=conectar();
        $d1=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tbl_noticias_blog where estatus='importante1' "); $d2=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tbl_noticias_blog where estatus='importante2' ");
        $d3=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tbl_noticias_blog where estatus='importante3' ");
                        while($titulo=mysqli_fetch_array($d1)){   
        ?>
        <div class="carousel-inner" style="border-radius:15px;">
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="first-slide" src="/noticias/img/formacion-1024x588.jpg" alt="First slide">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-left">
                        <h1>
                            <?php echo $titulo['titulo']; ?>
                        </h1>
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $titulo['dlarga'];?>
                        </p>
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="irnoti(<?php echo $titulo['id'];?>);" role="button"><span>Ver detalles</span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php }while($titulo=mysqli_fetch_array($d2)){    ?>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="second-slide" src="/noticias/img/slide-1240x327.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h1>
                            <?php echo $titulo['titulo']; ?>
                        </h1>
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $titulo['dlarga'];?>
                        </p>
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="irnoti(<?php echo $titulo['id'];?>);" role="button"><span>Ver detalles</span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php }while($titulo=mysqli_fetch_array($d3)){    ?>
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="third-slide" src="/noticias/img/prevencion-riesgos-laborales.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-right">
                        <h1>
                            <?php echo $titulo['titulo']; ?>
                        </h1>
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $titulo['dlarga'];?>
                        </p>
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="irnoti(<?php echo $titulo['id'];?>);" role="button"><span>Ver detalles</span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>


        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
        </a>
</div>
```

**navDerecho.php**

```
   <nav class="navbar-light bg-transparent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ">

        <?php

                    $obtenermenu=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tblnoticias_menu where descripcion='EVALUACIONES' ");
                    while($menu=mysqli_fetch_array($obtenermenu))
                    {
                        $submenu=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tblnoticias_submenu where idopcion='$menu[idopcion]' and estado=1 Order By PosS");
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($submenu)>0) 
                        {
                            ?>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown mr-auto">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span><?php echo utf8_encode($menu['descripcion']); ?></span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
                    <?php
                            while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($submenu))
                            {
                                ?>

                        <li>
                            <a style="text-decoration: none;color:black" href="<?php echo " /../../ ".$row1['url'];?>">
                                <?php echo utf8_encode($row1['descripcion']); ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <?php
                        }
                    }

            ?>



                <?php
    mysqli_close($link);

?>


    </ul>
</nav>
```

Agradecería mucho si alguien pudiera decirme cuál es el error y por qué el `div` no se está cerrando como corresponde ya que yo por mi parte no logré ubicar el `div` mal cerrado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en carusel.php y ocurre porque falta cerrar algunos `div`. Es algo que se podría ver claramente si el código estuviese indentado de un modo más consistente; Recuerda que un código limpio es un código más fácil de mantener.

Éste es el código de tu fichero, con una indentación diferente y comentarios donde hay errores potenciales (aunque realmente el problema es uno solo de ellos):

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
    </ol>
    <?php
        $link=conectar();
        $d1=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tbl_noticias_blog where estatus='importante1' "); 
        $d2=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tbl_noticias_blog where estatus='importante2' ");
        $d3=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tbl_noticias_blog where estatus='importante3' ");

        while($titulo=mysqli_fetch_array($d1)){   
    ?>
    <div class="carousel-inner" style="border-radius:15px;"> <!-- POSIBLE ERROR: ESTE DIV DEBERÍA ESTAR FUERA DEL WHILE PARA QUE NO SE ABRIESE CADA VEZ --> 
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="first-slide" src="/noticias/img/formacion-1024x588.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-left">
                    <h1><?php echo $titulo['titulo']; ?></h1>
                    <p><?php echo $titulo['dlarga'];?></p>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="irnoti(<?php echo $titulo['id'];?>);" role="button"><span>Ver detalles</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    <!-- POSIBLE ERROR: AQUÍ TE FALTARÍA CERRAR EL DIV .carousel-inner -->        
    <?php 
        }
        while($titulo=mysqli_fetch_array($d2)){    
    ?>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="second-slide" src="/noticias/img/slide-1240x327.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h1><?php echo $titulo['titulo']; ?></h1>
                <p><?php echo $titulo['dlarga'];?></p>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="irnoti(<?php echo $titulo['id'];?>);" role="button"><span>Ver detalles</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
        }
        while($titulo=mysqli_fetch_array($d3)){    
    ?>
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="third-slide" src="/noticias/img/prevencion-riesgos-laborales.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-right">
                <h1><?php echo $titulo['titulo']; ?></h1>
                <p><?php echo $titulo['dlarga'];?></p>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="irnoti(<?php echo $titulo['id'];?>);" role="button"><span>Ver detalles</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- POSIBLE ERROR: CIERRE INNECESARIO DE UN DIV -->
    <?php 
        } 
    ?>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

El problema real es que la apertura y cierre del `div` con clase `carousel-inner` debería encontrarse fuera de los bucles `while` (ahora mismo la apertura está en el primer bucle `while` y el cierra está en el último bucle `while` por lo que vas a ver errores, especialmente si el número de iteraciones no es el mismo en los dos bucles).

La solución sería mover esas apertura y cierre a fuera de los bucles. Algo así:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" style="border-radius:15px;">
        <?php
        $link=conectar();
        $d1=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tbl_noticias_blog where estatus='importante1' "); 
        $d2=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tbl_noticias_blog where estatus='importante2' ");
        $d3=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tbl_noticias_blog where estatus='importante3' ");

        while($titulo=mysqli_fetch_array($d1)){   
        ?>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="first-slide" src="/noticias/img/formacion-1024x588.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-left">
                    <h1><?php echo $titulo['titulo']; ?></h1>
                    <p><?php echo $titulo['dlarga'];?></p>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="irnoti(<?php echo $titulo['id'];?>);" role="button"><span>Ver detalles</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>       
        <?php 
        }
        while($titulo=mysqli_fetch_array($d2)){    
        ?>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="second-slide" src="/noticias/img/slide-1240x327.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h1><?php echo $titulo['titulo']; ?></h1>
                    <p><?php echo $titulo['dlarga'];?></p>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="irnoti(<?php echo $titulo['id'];?>);" role="button"><span>Ver detalles</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
        }
        while($titulo=mysqli_fetch_array($d3)){    
        ?>
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="third-slide" src="/noticias/img/prevencion-riesgos-laborales.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-right">
                    <h1><?php echo $titulo['titulo']; ?></h1>
                    <p><?php echo $titulo['dlarga'];?></p>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="irnoti(<?php echo $titulo['id'];?>);" role="button"><span>Ver detalles</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
        } 
        ?>

    </div> <!-- cierre de carousel-inner -->

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Alvaro, busque y busque y gracias a ti cambie el código y se soluciono todo yo por mi parte fui ciego para ver el error, alguna recomendación aparte de identar para ver posibles errores
Muchas gracias, muy agradecido.

Comment: Alvaro, despues de hacer ese cambio se paraliza el slider en el slide1 y se pega, aparte de eso el slide 2 se expande y se les quita la propiedad de border-radius, me e dado cuenta por suerte ahora despues de 2 dias.